# Sign out issue with ACS ADFS

Tags: logout, adfs, acs

I am using ACS and ADFS for single sign on. Sign in works perfectly fine. No issues.

We are using persistent cookie.

Sign out works fine but below is the issue.

1) If I open IE, login and log out in same IE window then it works perfectly fine.
2) If I open IE, login and close browser. Again hit the same url, you will be logged in. In this case sign out does not work and it throws below error.

"The wtrealm parameter is missing or incorrect. Try clearing all of your browser cookies, and then close all browser windows."

Please note, with the same IE session it works perfectly fine.

I could sense that issue is with ACSSignout cookies but not sure how to handle this.